# Error When Attempting to Run sudo GUI Program in Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: lubuntu, xorg

Whenever I attempt to run a GUI program as sudo from LXTerminal, I get this error:

```
No protocol specified

** (aptik-gtk:2701): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(aptik-gtk:2701): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I know that Mir display server doesn't belong there. Lubuntu uses only the x.org display server. I confirmed that it isn't installed. So there must be some /home file referencing it, as a result of transferring the /home data from an Ubuntu 14.04 backup to my Lubuntu /home. I tried uninstalling x11, reconfiguring x11, deleting ~/.config and nothing works.